# How to get polygons contained within another polygon, including those that touch the border in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery, geospatial, spatial-query

I'm trying to get blockgroups contains within a designated market area polygon in BigQuery. I've tried using `st_contains` and `st_covers` but I still only get the completely contained ones (and not the bordering ones:

```
SELECT a.blockgroup_geom as the_geom,
a.geo_id,
c.total_pop 

FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_blockgroups.us_blockgroups_national` a

join `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.blockgroup_2018_5yr` c
 
on a.geo_id = c.geo_id

join `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.designated_market_area` b
on st_covers(b.dma_geom,a.blockgroup_geom)
where b.dma_name = 'Milwaukee, WI'
```

[image]

What do I need to do to get all of the blockgroups within the dma polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the two datasets are not exactly aligned, so any slight discrepancies between the two polygons, or errors due to planar to spherical conversion prevent perfect nesting of the polygons.

This post has deeper discussion and an idea how to handle this: https://mentin.medium.com/creating-spatial-hierarchy-2ba5488eac0a

Here I would try `ST_Intersects` condition and check area of intersection to see if the larger part of the blockgroup belongs to DMA:

```
SELECT a.blockgroup_geom as the_geom,
  a.geo_id,
  c.total_pop,
  (st_area(st_intersection(b.dma_geom,a.blockgroup_geom))
       > 0.75 * st_area(a.blockgroup_geom)) as mostly

FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_blockgroups.us_blockgroups_national` a
join `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.blockgroup_2018_5yr` c
on a.geo_id = c.geo_id
join `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.designated_market_area` b
on st_intersects(b.dma_geom,a.blockgroup_geom)
where b.dma_name = 'Milwaukee, WI'
```

Does this result make sense? I've colored green polygons with mostly = true, and blue those with mostly = false:
[image]